# What does one gain from using a UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

Why not use a UIViewController with a TableView embedded in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UITableViewController has three properties:

1. tableView;
2. clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear;
3. refreshControl.

Also, you can create Static Cells in Interface Builder only in UITableViewController.

If you need anything from above - use it instead of UIViewController subclass.

Answer (score 1):

`UITableViewController` is a "shortcut" that is useful in situations when you need a simple table with static data, archived in a NIB/Storyboard. Using `UITableViewController` lets you get most of the behavior for free, without the need to write and manage a special data source for it.

Other than that situation, `UITableViewController` gives you very little on top of `UIViewController` with an embedded `UITableView`.